# How can download the pdf when create in smarty the pdf created from fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, header, smarty, fpdf

Hi i need to create a download line of pdf in smarty i have been makes  from fpdf, in the fire bug show the pdf file,but i can create a download link for that in smarty my code is below.

```
$content = $this->view->fetch($pdf->Output());
 $router->disableRender();
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="doc.pdf"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile(doc.pdf);
    die;
```

Please help me thax adv........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code, you're saying

```
$content = $this->view->fetch($pdf->Output());
 $router->disableRender();
```

then at the bottom, you say

```
ob_clean();
flush();

readfile(doc.pdf);
die;
```

Now, outside of the fact that this should be causing a PHP warning -- undefined constant doc.pdf, assuming a string, etc -- this code doesn't do what you think it does.  At no point do you write the PDF contents to disk, so how do you expect that reading it from disk is going to work?

You need to either write `$content` to the file before emitting it, or you need to just `echo $content`.

Did you even *try* troubleshooting this?

Comment: `echo $content.` nothing happen just display the output in firebug only `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to parse resource name ""' in /var/user/mohan/site/smarty_internal_template.php:941` error was show......